# How to read many rows of text as the same oberseration into SAS?

Tags: sas

```
I have a dataset stored as text. It looks like this:
```

[data in text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Adaj.png)

```
I want to read this dateset into SAS like:
```

[dataset I want it to be in SAS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fz9Qh.png)

```
This is my code now:
proc import datafile="myfile" out=mydata DBMS=dlm;
delimiter='09'x;
getnames=no;
run;
```

But the result just looks like which stored in text. How to revise the code? Thank you.

Comment: Post the data as text rather than taking a photograph of it.  Don't ask SAS to guess at what is in the file by calling `PROC IMPORT`, just write a `DATA` step to read it directly.  What is the meaning of the semi-colons in the file?  Why is one on a line by itself and another at the end of a line with data?

Answer (score 1):

Your file looks to have one value per row.  Assuming you want to read them into three columns then just let SAS do it for you.  You can try to eliminate the any tabs or semi-colon by asking it to treat them as delimiters.  You could try using the FLOWOVER option (which is the default) on the INFILE statement to have it automatically go to the next row.

```
data want ;
   dlm='09'X || ';' ;
   infile 'myfile' dlm=dlm flowover ;
   input id $ val1 val2 ;
run;
```

Now if your data has blank rows you might get out of synch and begin trying to read the text strings like `AA` into the numeric variables.  So if that it true you might try telling it to read exactly three rows for every observation.

```
data want ;
   infile 'myfile' truncover ;
   input id $ / val1 / val2 ;
run;
```